# restore influxdb backup inside travis-CI failed with an error: restore: open /var/lib/influxdb/meta/node.json: no such file or directory

Tags: java, backup, travis-ci, restore, influxdb

Environment: 
OS: Linux travis-job-50c7192e-954f-4101-8363-813e067b3b40 4.4.0-101-generic #124~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 10 19:05:36 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

influxdb version: influxdb_1.2.2_amd64

travis-CI job log: https://travis-ci.org/y1j2x34/spring-influxdb-orm/builds/540383484

backup files: 
https://github.com/y1j2x34/spring-influxdb-orm/tree/master/data/backups

I was restored the backup data correctly in my cent OS server, but failed in 
travis-CI, I don't know what caused this error.

The following command is how I backup the test database data:

```sh
influxd backup --database test path/to/project/data/backups
```

and restore backups commands:

```sh
influxd restore -metadir /var/lib/influxdb/meta ./data/backups
influxd restore -database test -datadir /var/lib/influxdb/data ./data/backups
```

The error message:

```sh
$ influxd restore -metadir /var/lib/influxdb/meta ./data/backups
Using metastore snapshot: data/backups/meta.00
restore: open /var/lib/influxdb/meta/node.json: no such file or directory
The command "influxd restore -metadir /var/lib/influxdb/meta ./data/backups" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/influxdb/meta /var/lib/influxdb/data
```

Problem solved！